# Kernel updates on 16.04

Tags: kernel

I have a couple of questions about kernel updates on 16.04 with no control panel, I'm hoping you can help me with!

I have 4.4.0-93 generic x86-64  installed on my machine. If I wanted to update this, should I stick with 4.4? If you look at http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline the latest version for 4.4 appears to be 4.4.120 updated on March 4th. Is it ok for me to move out of 4.4, for example there's 4.9.86 also updated on March 4th? It is confusing as to which version you should be using!

I would only want to upgrade for security reasons - is there anyway of being notified that you should upgrade for these reasons and advice on which version to install (further to my point above)?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check more info about particular kernel releases here https://www.kernel.org/ , personally I installed `4.15.7` but You can choose any that will work with Your hardware. Just install selected from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline and see for yourself.

Comment: Many thanks Michal. I'll take a look at kernel.org